# Why private static method is used when working with Task

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

This code has been taken from another website :

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
public class Program {

    private static Int32 Sum(Int32 n)
    {
        Int32 sum = 0;
        for (; n > 0; n--)
        checked { sum += n; } 
        return sum;
    }

    public static void Main() {
        Task<int32> t = new Task<int32>(n => Sum((Int32)n), 1000);
        t.Start();
        t.Wait(); 

        // Get the result (the Result property internally calls Wait) 
        Console.WriteLine("The sum is: " + t.Result);   // An Int32 value
    }
}
```

I don't understand the purpose of using the private static method and not any other normal public method.

Thanks

Comment: What method are you talking about?

Comment: private static Int32 Sum(Int32 n)

Comment: Because the method is for just the program class, so that's why its private

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The method is static because it's used from a static context, so it can't be non-static.

The method is probably private because there's no reason to make it public.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you have Main method is `static`  and you can not call non-static method from `static` method without make object of that class as non-static methods are called with object.

If make the Sum method non-static you will have to call it on object of Program class

```
private Int32 Sum(Int32 n)
{
      //your code
}
```

Calling will be changed as

```
Task<Int32> t = new Task<Int32>(n => new Program().Sum((Int32)n), 1000);
```

Comment: *and you can not call non-static method from static method* ? It should be *you can not call non-static method from static method* **without an object reference**

Comment: Thanks @SriramSakthivel, nice of you.